# Redirecting to another page and passing variables after clicking a submit button

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, forms, reload

I have script that has a form that is self submitting. And on that php script I insert the data into the database. I would like to store the last inserted id using mysql_insert_id() and use it in another form that is also self submitting.

What i want to do is after the submission of form 1, store the last inserted id, reload the page and pass the last inserted id in the url (reload using javascript). www.web.com?inserted_id=12312

and get that id and use it in another form.

How am i going to do that?

I can't load using jquery, here's my code in reloading the page:

```
window.location = '<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]?>'
```

Comment: you cant load using jQuery. Does it mean that jQuery doesnt work in your Wordpress? or you dont want to use it?

Answer (score 1):

What i want to do is after the submission of form 1, store the last inserted id, reload the page and pass the last inserted id in the url.

---Use PHP sessions to save the last inserted id. then you can use it wherever you want.

Comment: I'm using wordpress and I'm trying to create a plugin. and they said wordpress doesnt have sessions

Comment: R u sure ?? check this : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32646/how-to-use-my-own-custom-session-value-in-wordpress